# Ubuntu 14.04 issue with torrent applications daemons crashing causing network issues

Tags: bittorrent, deluge, utorrent

Im having alot of issues with ubuntu 14.04 server when i install torrent applications. I have tried both  deluge and utorrent server. I have reinstalled ubuntu about 6 times (im now ghosting a working copy as its quicker then setting up samba share all the time). The primary purpose of my ubuntu server is nas storage for movies,tv and files, but I want to also have torrent daemon on server so it can be be logged onto from other windows computers and eventually store VPN on it.

The problem starts when I start running the daemons they keep crashing all the time! and downloads really slow (if at all). It also effects the mounted media drives when accessing them over the network, it keeps freezing and crashing explorer. At first I thought it was specific applications but now im starting to think its something in ubuntu if both application are having the exact same issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions? could it be a package preinstalled on ubuntu? Im at a loss. Thanks

Comment: If deluged is crashing then you need an Apport trace and report it as a bug...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are maxing out your network.  Your Torrent client should have a setting to limit the number of concurrent IP connections.  You also will need to specify different working ports for each client if you are using more than 1 since you are saying Daemons it leads me to believe you have multiple clients running each needs its own port that is port forwarded if behind the router for it to function.  Then if behind a router you would need to also specify the port range [as files download the client uses different ports for the different connections and again these need to be port forwarded as well.  I suggest you use the 10,000 area ports [I usually set like 10100 - 10102 for the different ports the client uses for the torrent networks and then set something like 10110-10140 for the range all set as both tcp and udp for the min - max port range for file downloads (I use qBittorrent which has the port range setting [newer version] some clients may lack the port range in advanced for magnet link *.tor file downloads and file downloads and if this is the case your client will run it just may not be as fast all the time as one you can specify).

Specifying at least 2 - 3 ports for each client instance you run should get you going and not having them conflict with each other (each one after the 1st you open will crash cause it can not use the same port already in use by the previous client instance), but specifying a different settings file for each one [if needed do a manual install installing multiple copies to different directories if the client does not already support custom settings file].

That should help get you running...

Comment: hey thanks for the response. Iv opened up port ranges in the router for both tcp/udp for ubuntu servers ip address they are:58846,8112, 9092 and for deluge outgoing ports
49161 to 49170

and deluge ingoing ports
49171 to 49180. All under ubuntu server ip address. how do you open the port for thin client/set it? Isnt the out going and in going ports for daemon? thanks

Comment: For the thin client?  You mean the Web Interface where you can view it's activity (or there are mobile clients that can connect to the web interface port and pull data to their GUI, but you are actually still using the HTTP server port of the Torrent client's HTTP server is running on)?  If so, I know in qBittorrent there is a speciifc set of settings for setting not only user / password and specifying certs if you wish to use HTTPS with it, but also for what port to use.  Once set you would do http://<IP OR DNS>:<PORT SPECIFIED> (ie http://localhost:10880) in your browser's address bar.